# Writing Jasmine test to check contents of h4 element

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I have a test where I am essentially checking for a h4 tag. Now within that tag i want to be able to check the contents that has been given within that. I seem to be writing the following test but it keeps failing .I am not sure what it is that I am missing or i am writing my test incorrectly:

```
describe('StatusAppComponent', () => {

  it('should consist of a heading four tag', () => {
   component.showBanner = true;
   fixture.detectChanges();
   const headingElems = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('h4'));
   expect(headingElems).toHaveText('WARNING')
```

});

My html is as follows :

```
<div *ngIf="this.showBanner">
  <div class="banner alert">
    <div class="page-section">
  <h4>WARNING</h4>
  {{this.message}}
</div>
```

Comment: Does the query return a node, or a node list? Maybe you need to `expect(headingElems[0])//...`

Comment: @mbojko See my comments below

Answer (score 0):

**`toHaveText()`** is no longer supported by jasmine. Use **`toBe`** instead like below

```
expect(headingElems[0].trim()).toBe("WARNING");
```

Comment: I get an error saying :

Cannot read property 'trim' of undefined

Comment: If i removed the trim property i then get a different error:

Error: Expected undefined to be 'WARNING'.

Comment: Looks like `h4` tag is not available in the view.

Comment: If you look at the html then it is @Karthick Manoharan

Comment: If i do the following then the test will pass : expect(headingElems).toBeTruthy();

Comment: can you `console.log(headingElems)` and share

Answer (score 0):

This is not always necessary, but sometimes you have to wait until the view is stable before querying for HTML elements.

```
it('should consist of a heading four tag', () => {
  component.showBanner = true;
  fixture.detectChanges();
  fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
    const headingElems = fixture.nativeElement.querySelector('h4');
    expect((headingElems.textContent as string).trim()).toBe('WARNING');
  });
});
```